# How to get an index of a specific Map inside a List?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a List of Maps

```
const myList = List([Map({name: 'arman'}), Map({name: 'abzal', age: 22}), Map({name: 'azat'})])
```

I want to get an index of, for example, the Map with `name: 'arman'`

Comment: FWIW, [*records*](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) seem to be a better solution than `Map` for your case.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the advice. Let's say I use Record instead, how do I get a specific Record inside a List?

Comment: Propably you are looking for [findIndex](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/findIndex) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such code:

```js
const index = myList.findIndex(one => one.get('name') === nameToSearch)
```